# Error when import Spark GaussianMixture

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I get following error

> object GaussianMixture is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml.clustering

when I try to do following import from spark-shell

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.GaussianMixture
```

As this is part of [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), I don't think any dependencies need to be added. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the GaussianMixture uses the `mllib` package. Try to import:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixture
```